# Submenu in a Bootstrap dropdown menu not working

Tags: bootstrap-4, frontend

I am having trouble getting my dropdown menu to properly function. The first level of dropdown is working fine, however the submenu I have is not opening. When I click it, it simply closes the menu without changing anything.

Below is the code I'm working with, and the submenu part that isn't appearing is the list containing "add item", "edit item", and "delete item"

```
    <div class="dropdown show">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                     {/*  This Line will hold the link to the User Management page  */}
                    <a className="dropdown-item " href="#"><Link to={'/missionReports'} className="nav-link">Mission Reports</Link></a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Data Management </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a className="dropdown-item " href="#"><Link to={'/AddInfo'} className="nav-link">Add Item</Link></a></li>
                        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><Link to={'/EditInfo'} className="nav-link">Edit Item</Link></a></li>
                        <li><a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><Link to={'/DeleteInfo'} className="nav-link">Delete Item</Link></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you working on ReactJs <Link> tag is used in React not in bootstrap. In ReactJs no <a> tag is not working properly. so, you can use <link> only. In react <link> tag is used for re-direct the page instead of <a> tag. For multilevel dropdown you can take hint / example from here: https://bootstrap-menu.com/detail-multilevel.html

Comment: I've tried taking out the anchor tags, but that still doesn't fix my problem. I even tried replacing everything with the code from the link you posted, but even then it still cuts off any submenus.

Answer (score 0):

### Check This One, It will help you.

It's a multi layered submenu dropdown. It's working for me. Please check and let me know.

---

> Change the CSS, acc. to your need.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

if ($(window).width() < 992) {
  $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).next('.submenu').length){
        $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
      }
      $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $(this).find('.submenu').hide();
  })
  });
}
```

```css
    .nav-item, .dropdown-item{
        background-color: lightgrey !important;
        color: black !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
    }
    .nav-item:hover, .dropdown-item:hover{
        background-color: grey !important;
        color: white !important;
        padding: 5px !important;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration: none !important;
        color: black !important;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <button class="navbar-toggler text-danger bg-white" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main_nav">My Multi-Layer Dropdown
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main_nav">

<ul class="navbar-nav list-unstyled">
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">First Level Item 1 </a>    
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">First Level Item 2 </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"> First Level Item 3    
            <span class="caret"></span> 
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second Level Item 3.1 </a> </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second Level Item 3.2 
                    <span class="caret"></span> 
                </a>
                <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Third Level Item 3.2.1</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="">Third Level Item 3.2.2
                            <span class="caret"></span> 
                        </a>
                        <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Forth Level Item 3.2.2.1</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Forth Level Item 3.2.2.2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Third Level Item 3.2.3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Third Level Item 3.2.4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Second Level Item 3.3 </a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>

</div> 
</nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check Code, and let me know it's working Fine or not.

---

> I have tried, both are correct. Use and change the CSS. I have done
> only for working submenu Dropdown. Both are same, some minor changes are their. > Hope you want the same. Let me know.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

if ($(window).width() < 992) {
  $('.dropdown-menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
      if($(this).next('.submenu').length){
        $(this).next('.submenu').toggle();
      }
      $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $(this).find('.submenu').hide();
  })
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"> Multiple submenu dropdown  </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 1 </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 2 » </a>
             <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Submenu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Submenu item 2</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Submenu item 3 » </a>
                    <ul class="submenu dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 1</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Multi level 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Submenu item 4</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="">Submenu item 5</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 3 </a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Dropdown item 4 </a>
        </li></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Turns out it absolutely was a CSS problem. This would have solved this error, but our team here wound up going in a different direction for UI design. Thanks for the help though!